# gtk printOperation without dialog

Tags: node.js, meteor, printing, gtk

I'm trying to make a printing routine without the dialog window, I understand that this is done using the PRINT option instead of PRINT_DIALOG.

```
Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG
Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT
```

The routine with the dialog option works accordingly, these options are captured with the "print.toFile(...)" function and read in the lines:

```
pageSetup.loadFile(Assets.absoluteFilePath('pagesetup.conf'));
printSettings.loadFile(Assets.absoluteFilePath('printsettings.conf'));
```

they appear in the logs.

But nothing happens, none of the events are fired ('begin-print', 'draw-page', or whatever).

I'm using the node-gtk package together with Meteor, this is evidenced in the "Assets.absoluteFilePath" ( Meteor ) function
and on all the other lines, which are in camelCase (node-gtk does this )

I don't believe these packages are the cause of the problems, it seems to me that something is missing, since the result is three (3 -> IN_PROGRESS).

And all the examples I find use the PRINT_DIALOG routine

```java
botao2.on('clicked', () => {
  let printSettings = new Gtk.PrintSettings();
  let pageSetup = new Gtk.PageSetup();
  pageSetup.loadFile(Assets.absoluteFilePath('pagesetup.conf'));
  printSettings.loadFile(Assets.absoluteFilePath('printsettings.conf'));
  let print = new Gtk.PrintOperation({
    //'allow-async': true,
  });
  print.setUnit(Gtk.Unit.NONE);
  print.setPrintSettings(printSettings);
  print.setDefaultPageSetup(pageSetup);
  print.setUseFullPage(true);
  print.setShowProgress(true);

  console.log({ pageSetup, printSettings });

  print.on('begin-print', (printContext, num) => {
    print.nPages = 1;
    width = Math.floor(printContext.getWidth());
    height = Math.floor(printContext.getHeight());
  });

  print.on('draw-page', (printContext) => {
    console.log('draw-page', printContext);
  });

  print.on('status-changed', (...args) => {
    console.log('status-changed', args);
  });

  print.on('done', (res) => {
    console.log('done', res);
  });

  console.log(print.run(Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT));  // always 3 -> IN_PROGRESS
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug present in GTK4, in GTK3 it works, the team has already fixed it, at the moment just wait to get to the distribution packages

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/4439